# FPDI remove page from PDF output

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf, fpdi

I'm using `FPDF` and `FPDI` to do the following

```
require_once('pdfs/fpdf.php');
require_once('pdfs/fpdi.php');

// initiate FPDI 
$pdf = new FPDI(); 
// set the sourcefile 
$pdf->setSourceFile('pdfs/originals/document.pdf'); 

//for ($i = 1; $i < 43; $i++) { 
for ($i = 1; $i < 10; $i++) { 

$pdf->AddPage();
$tplidx = $pdf->ImportPage($i); 
$pdf->useTemplate($tplidx, 10, 0, 200);
```

With that is there any way of hiding a page from the final output depending on if statements? For example if `$middlepages` is equal to or more than 2, I need to show 2 certain pages, but if `$middlepages` is 1, I only need to show the first page of the 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like nobody got to this question... until now. Here's the basics of the FPDI workflow, straight from their [documentation](http://manuals.setasign.com/fpdi-manual/the-fpdi-class/#index-2):

1. Define the document to take pages from
2. Import an existing page of the document
3. Use the imported page on a page created with FPDF

This is a simple FPDI example in action:

```
$pdf = new FPDI();
$pageCount = $pdf->setSourceFile('file.pdf');

//  Iterate through every page
for( $pageNo=1; $pageNo<=$pageCount; $pageNo++ )
{
    $templateId = $pdf->importPage($pageNo);

    //  Determine if page is portrait or landscape
    $size = $pdf->getTemplateSize($templateId);

    if( $size['w']>$size['h'] )
        $pageFormat = 'L';  //  landscape
    else
        $pageFormat = 'P';  //  portrait

    $pdf->addPage($pageFormat,array($size['w'],$size['h']));
    $pdf->useTemplate($templateId);
}

$pdf->Output();
```

Great! Now let's look at your specific desire, which is to add only a certain amount of pages. As you can see, we use a `for` loop to iterate through all the imported pages of the document, starting from page 1 and going to the last page, inclusive. If you wanted to change which pages are added, all you have to do is change the start and end points for the `for` loop. The concept is not to "hide" a page, but rather to only import pages we want to see in the final result.

Here's a simple example. I'm going to define some constants to represent different page-adding schemes:

```
const PDF_FIRSTPAGE     = 1;
const PDF_MIDDLEPAGES   = 2;
```

Before my page import loop, I will go through this switch to determine my start and end pages for each condition. This is after initially declaring the PDF. Notice how I check values against `$pageCount` to ensure that I do not attempt to import pages that do not exist:

```
switch( $loopCondition )
{
    //  By default, include everything
    default:
        $pageStart  = 1;
        $pageEnd    = $pageCount;
        break;
    //  Include only the first page
    case PDF_FIRSTPAGE:
        $pageStart  = 1;
        $pageEnd    = 1;
        break;
    //  Include pages 2-4, but only if those pages exist
    case PDF_MIDDLEPAGES:
        if( $pageCount>=2 )
        {
            $pageStart = 2;
            if( $pageCount>=4 )
            {
                $pageEnd = 4;
            }
            else
            {
                $pageEnd = $pageCount;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $pageStart  = 1;
            $pageEnd    = 1;
        }
        break;
}
```

Finally, I modify the `for` loop you saw above:

```
for( $pageNo=$pageStart; $pageNo<=$pageEnd; $pageNo++ )
```

Now if I set my variable `$loopCondition` equal to `PDF_MIDDLEPAGES` I only get pages 2-4 as an output if the document originally had 4 or more pages. If I use a 3-page document, I get pages 2-3. You should alter the conditions to best suit your needs, as I do not know the nature of the PDF files you plan to import, but I think with this post you should be able to figure out everything you need to know on how to use FPDI to selectively include certain pages from a source PDF document. Happy coding!

Comment: This is a much more natural way of coding it than the bodge job that I ended up with!